# Field is required when other three fields are empty

Tags: laravel

I have 4 input fields. 1 of them has to be filled.

My fields :

```
<input name="name" placeholder="Name">
<input name="hair_style" placeholder="Style">
<input name="hair_color" placeholder="Color">
<input name="options" placeholder="Options">
```

My function

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required_if:hair_style,0,',
]);
```

So when `hair_style` is 0. Input field name has to be filled. This works but.. I want it like this below but I don't know how:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required_if:hair_style,empty AND hair_color,empty AND options,empty,',
]);
```

It has to work like this. When `hair_style`, `hair_color` and `options` are empty `name` has to be filled. But is this possible with `required_if` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try as:

```
'name' => 'required_if:hair_style,0|required_if:hair_color,0||required_if:options,0',
```

**Update**

You can [conditionally add rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#conditionally-adding-rules) as:

```
$v = Validator::make($data, [
   'name' => 'min:1',
]);


$v->sometimes('name', 'required', function($input) {
   return ($input->hair_style == 0 && $input->hair_color == 0 && $input->options == 0);
});
```

You can add more logics in the closure if you required...like `empty` checks.

Comment: I want to check all the three fields at once and check if it's empty and not 0.

Comment: Thank you for your time but I found my answer!

Comment: I answered it on this page!

Answer (score 0):

So all I had to do was :

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required_without_all:hair_style, hair_color, options',
]);
```

for more information check https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-required-without-all